# How do I pass a variable length array in a function which receives a variable length array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I found a way to pass a variable length array in C++. But it fails 'wrap' function in below code. Actually I want to wrap format function in my project.
What am i doing wrong in my code?

test code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string>

void log(const char* format, ...)
{
    va_list argptr;
    va_start(argptr, format);

    int length = _vscprintf(format, argptr);
    char* buf_ = new char [length + 1];
    int ret = vsnprintf(buf_, 1000, format, argptr);

    if (ret >= 0) {
        std::cout << buf_ << std::endl;
    }

    delete[] buf_;
    va_end(argptr);
}

void wrap(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);
    log(format, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}


int main()
{
    log( "direct = %d", 1);
    wrap("wrap   = %d", 1);

    return 0;
}
```

the result is here.

```
direct = 1
wrap   = 15137088 // what's happen?
```

Comment: your log() function will be called from "wrap()" with a va_list as argument following the format argument, rather than the actual arguments passed to wrap. I don't think this can easily be done like this.

Comment: BTW, with C++11, you may use variadic template instead: `template <typename ...Ts> void wrap(const char* format, Ts&&...args) { log(format, std::forward<Ts>(args)...); }`

Answer (score 1):

> I found a way to pass a variable length array in C++

That isn't a variable-length array, and it isn't really idiomatic C++. The `...` is a variable-length argument list, and is available in C.

The simplest reasonable way to wrap your log function is the variadic template one, which can simply be written as:

```
template <typename... Args>
void wrap(const char *format, Args&&... args) {
    log(format, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

---

In the log function itself, `vsnprintf` returns the number of bytes that *would have been written*, in the event it fills the buffer. So, you can always just call it once with an optimistic buffer size, and grow the buffer if necessary: you don't need the non-standard `_vscprintf`. That would look something like:

```
void log(const char* format, ...)
{
    va_list argptr;
    va_start(argptr, format);

    static const size_t DefaultSize = 200;
    // pick some value that makes sense ^^ here
    char buf[DefaultSize];
    int rv = vsnprintf(buf, DefaultSize, format, argptr);
    if (rv < 0) {
        // we can't return errors with this prototype:
        // should it throw?
        return;
    }
    if (rv >= DefaultSize) {
        vector<char> dynbuf(rv+1);
        rv = vsnprintf(&dynbuf[0], dynbuf.size(), format, argptr);
        std::cout << &dynbuf[0] << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << buf << std::endl;
    }

    va_end(argptr);
}
```

Note also that `wrap` knows the types of all its arguments, but that information is discarded when you call the C-style variadic function `log`. You might consider Boost.Format as a type-safe alternative - as a bonus, it will manage the buffer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a va_list where a variable number of argumets (x, y, z) is expected isn't designed to work.

To achieve what you want, you need to do something like this:

```
void log_args(const char* format, va_list& argptr)
{
    // I'm unsure on this... you may possibly need to make a separate
    // copy of the va_list to pass in to each of _vscprintf and vsnprintf.  
    va_list second;
    va_copy(second, argptr);

    int length = _vscprintf(format, argptr);
    char* buf_ = new char [length + 1];

    int ret = vsnprintf(buf_, 1000, format, second);

    if (ret >= 0) {
        std::cout << buf_ << std::endl;
    }

    delete[] buf_;
}

void log(const char* format, ...)
{
    va_list argptr;
    va_start(argptr, format);    
    log_args(argptr);
    va_end(argptr);
}

void wrap(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);
    log_args(format, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}
```

In this example 'wrap' and 'log' appear the same... but I presume you want to do something additional in your real wrap function otherwise why would you be asking this question.

Comment: Wow! You're really great! I appreciate your work. Yeah, I know my wrap code is a just fake which has no meaning in this case.

Comment: No, he's not really great. That is a terrible use of `new` and `delete`, and he also passed a magic buffer size to `vsnprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

In c++11, you can use [variadic templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)

```
#include <iostream>

void tprintf(const char* format) // base function
{
    std::cout << format;
}

template<typename T, typename... Targs>
void tprintf(const char* format, T value, Targs... Fargs) // recursive variadic function
{
    for ( ; *format != '\0'; format++ ) {
        if ( *format == '%' ) {
           std::cout << value;
           tprintf(format+1, Fargs...); // recursive call
           return;
        }
        std::cout << *format;
    }
}

int main()
{
    tprintf("direct = %\n", 1);
    tprintf("wrap   = %\n", 1);
    return 0;
}
```